# How to read files in other directory in python

Tags: python

I want to open and read some files from different folders in Python3. The structure is like:

```
snapshot
  - folder1
      - file 1
      - file 2
  - folder2
      - file 3
      - file 4
```

I tried using `pathlib`, but it is showed "\" instead "/". Is there other way to do it? The ideal result I want is this:

```
"./snapshot/folder1/file 1"
"./snapshot/folder1/file 2"
"./snapshot/folder1/file 3"
"./snapshot/folder1/file 4"
```

This is my code:

```
folders = Path('Snapshot/')**strong text**
for folder in folders.iterdir():
    files = Path(f'./{folder}/')
    for file in files.iterdir():
```

Comment: You say your code showed "\", but the code you've shared so far doesn't show anything at all. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `file 3` and `file 4` are not in `folder1`. So what logic determines that conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just:

```
from pathlib import Path
folders = Path('Snapshot/')
for folder in folders.iterdir():
    files = Path(folder)
    for file in files.iterdir():
```

The string expansion is not needed.

I also don't know what you mean with '\'. Why do you care at all? I thought you want to read the contents of a file?

perhaps you show the lines after the last for loop?
Example:

```
from pathlib import Path

folders = Path('Snapshot/')
for folder in folders.iterdir():
    if not folder.is_dir():
        continue
    entries = Path(folder)
    for entry in entries.iterdir():
        if not entry.is_file():
            continue
        print("fname", str(entry))
        with open(entry, "rb") as fin:
            data = fin.read()
        print(len(data), "bytes")
```

Are you running on windows?
Then it would be possible, that your path name is 'normalized' (using the default directory separator '\')

Comment: Where does `Path` come from?

Comment: Path comes from pathlib (as mentioned in the question). I just copied the snippet from the question and fixed it, but you're right. better to show the imports to avoid any ambiguity

Comment: I edited my answer. the full example recurses now into directories and skips files in the first level. in the second level it opens the file (just to show, that open() works) by reading the file contents and counting the length.
I also avoided the variable name file, as it is also a python keyword

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

dirpath = 'snapshot'
for root, dirnames, fnames in os.walk(dirpath):
    for fname in fnames:
        print(os.path.join('.', root, fname))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

for folder in os.listdir('snapshot'):

    folder_path = os.path.join('snapshot', folder)

    for file in os.listdir(folder_path):

        # do stuff
```